# Using destructor in class

Tags: c++, class, constructor, copy, destructor

I've got a project in C++ that uses classes(quite basic elements).
My class looks like this:

```
class vehicule: public frane,public motor,public directie,public noxe,public caroserie
{
    char tip[40];
    int placfatacant,placfatatot;
    static const int placfatapret=18;
    int placspatecant,placspatetot;
    static const int placspatepret=15;
public:
    vehicule()
    void settip(char)
    void verifauto()
;};
```

I've been told I have to use copy constructor and destructor. I have some examples,but both use dynamic allocation. Now my question is:what should my copy constructor/destructor do as I don't have dynamic allocated memory to copy/delete? Or should I declare the data as

```
int *placfatacant
```

and then use

```
delete placfatacant
```

?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are not dealing with any memory management the defaults will work just fine.

Comment: Yes,that's what I know too. The point is,this project is for school and one of the things that are assessed by the teacher is the use of constructor,copy constructor and destructor. Do you have any idea how to use the last 2,to prove that I know how to use them?

Comment: If your instructor says you need to have them the I would guess that you are supposed to using some sort of memory management in you class.

Comment: If my answer answer your problem please accept it as answer using the green cross. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is for school purpose you can change :

```
// From:
char tip[40];

// To:
char * tip;`
```

And then in your constructor you will make:

```
tip = new char[40]();
```

Now you have to create a copy constructor like this one:

```
vehicule(const vehicule & toCopy)
{
    tip = new char[40]();
    strcpy(tip, toCopy.tip);
}
```

Your destructor just need to deallocate `tip`:

```
~vehicule()
{
    delete tip;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You only need to declare a constructor if you need to handle the deletion of dynamically allocated variables, as you said. In general, for every `new`, there must be a `delete`.

I don't see any `new`'d objects in your class, so I would just let the compiler-generated destructor/copy constructor do its thing. Your class is entirely statically allocated and will be deleted when it falls out of scope of the context in which it is used.

Comment: Yes,that's what I know too. The point is,this project is for school and one of the things that are assessed by the teacher is the use of constructor,copy constructor and destructor. Do you have any idea how to use the last 2,to prove that I know how to use them?